# What is "All..." that just appeared in my Finder sidebar?

Tags: macos, finder, snow-leopard, sidebar

This "Network Neighborhood" icon recently appeared on my Finder's sidebar, pointing to some items I haven't seen before, all of them empty.

[image: screenshot of Finder]

- Procyon is an Apple Time Capsule.
- Skype is running but why are there two links?
- 'messenger.live.com' doesn't make much sense; I don't use messenger and it doesn't appear in Activity Monitor or in `ps -A`.

What would cause the sidebar link to appear in the first place?

MacOS 10.6.8
The most recent Software Update was iTunes to v11.2.1, applied two days ago. I noticed this change in approximately that time-frame - but, iTunes?!

Comment: This isn't the normal Finder. PathFinder, TotalFinder…?

Comment: Indeed - it's TotalFinder running over Finder.

Comment: Weird!! I relaunched plain Finder and the sidebar item was gone. I launched TotalFinder again, and it remains gone!